# Using STL queue with custom data structure

Tags: c++, stl, queue

I'm trying to use STL queue in one of my functions. Inside the function, I have the following code:

```
struct node {
    int player1X, player1Y, player2X, player2Y;
    int steps;
};
queue<node> q;
```

But somehow this queue won't initialise witout errors (`queue<int>` works fine). What am I doing wrong?

PS There are 4 errors on the line with a declaration:

```
error: template argument for ‘template<class> class std::allocator’ uses local type ‘PathFinding::minTurns(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >)::node’

error:   trying to instantiate ‘template<class> class std::allocator’

error: template argument 2 is invalid

error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
```

All 4 errors disappear if I exchange `node` to `int`.

Comment: What's the error the compiler reports?

Comment: [that should work](http://ideone.com/OQyjVB)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to define the structure outside the function in a namespace for example in the global namespace. It seems you have an old compiler.